# Comparing PID's in bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to something very simple and I'm having lots of trouble with it.

I've got a bash script that I have to write for class that performs a function similar to pstree.  It reports pstree for itself.  The output should look like:

```
PID
|
PPID
|
.
.
.
|
1
```

Here is my code so far:

```
ps -ef>tmp1.txt                   #save ps -ef to a file
pid=$$      
echo $pid                         #print first PID
while [ $pid != "1" ]
do
    cat tmp1.txt | while read line    #read in ps -ef file line by line
    do
        tmp=$(echo $line | cut -f2 -d' ') #return only the PID column of ps -ef
        if [$pid == $tmp]                 #compare current PID to temp PID of current line
        then
            echo "|"
            pid=$(echo $line | cut -f3 -d' ') #if they're the same we found the PPID, so save it
            echo $pid                         #and echo it
        fi
    done
done
```

Where it's failing is at the comparison statement:

```
if [$pid == $tmp]
```

I get a not found error.  Got any ideas why the comparison isn't working?  Thanks for any help in advance and if I can clarify anything please tell me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single equals sign is used to compare strings (`if [ $pid = $tmp ]`).

Comment: And you need spaces around the `[` and `]` characters.

Comment: @Keith: right, thanks, I wrote that correctly but didn't point it out.

Comment: Ok made that change plus I added the semi-colon after it.  Still doesn't work completely, but I'm making progress.  Thanks guys

Comment: @Casbar77: What semicolon?  If you're still having trouble tracking it down, please update your question with the modified code.  Oh, and indenting it properly would make it more readable.

Answer (score 2):

I've edited your question to indent the code. It's much, much easier to read when you indent each while and if statement.

The line you're complaining about is

```
   if [$pid == $tmp]
```

That's invalid for a couple of reasons already pointed out. Unlike other programming languages, BASH uses a single equals sign, and you must keep a blank space around the square brackets. The square bracket is a command, and must be white space separated. It's an alias for the `test` command. This line should look like this:

```
   if [ $pid = $tmp ]
```

Now, `=` is a string comparison, if you're doing a numeric comparison, you should use `-eq` instead:

```
   if [ $pid -eq $tmp ]
```

And, since `[` is an alias to the `test` command, it could be written like this (but rarely is):

```
   if test $pid -eq $tmp
```

However, it does show you why you need a space around the square braces.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback as well as indenting the code.  Lack of indenting was a copy and paste issue.  I was moving between too many environments and forgot to add them back.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not efficient. Try with awk, without temporary file and nested loop:

```
ps -eo pid,ppid | awk -v START=$$ '
{ PPID[$1]=$2 } # (for each line) create PPIDs table record
END { if (PPID[START]) { # (when done) if starting pid is correct
    for(pid=START; pid!=1; pid=PPID[pid]) # print the tree
      printf "%d\n|\n", pid;
    print 1;
  }
}'
```

Comment: I know it's inefficient.  I was required to code it this way.  However, I agree with you.  Doing all of it inside awk is superior.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you interested my final code looks like this:

```
echo $pid
while [ $pid != "1" ]
do
     while read line
     do
          tmp="$(echo $line | cut -f2 -d' ')"
          if [ $pid = $tmp ];
          then
               pid="$(echo $line | cut -f3 -d' ')"
          fi
     done<./tmp1.txt
     echo "|"
     echo $pid
done
```

Thanks to all of you jedi masters out there.

Comment: You could still avoid a temporary file (always a hassle, and you don't seem to be deleting it even in the normal success case) and do the splitting in the `read`.  Something like `ps -ef | while read owner p pp rest ; do case $pid in $p) pid=$pp;; esac; done`